# System Freezes When Installing Package/Updating Ubuntu OS

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, software-center

I recently just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Surface Pro 3 and have issues when installing a large package, or update the os itself whether it's through "sudo apt-get upgrade", or by just using the software center. The system completely freezes during this, keeping me from using keyboard/mice input. I usually reboot my system to get Ubuntu up and running again, but it never fixes the freezing from upgrading. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Any error messages when trying to apt-get update/upgrade? If so please edit your question and add them.

Comment: No error messages, the system just freezes.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a standard x86 install I would say  have a look at Apt logs.

`tail -n 100 /var/log/apt/*`

but the Surface platform doesn't seem to play nice with the standard kernel and seems to require work arounds.

[Installing Ubuntu on Surface pro 4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791976/installing-ubuntu-on-surface-pro-4)